# Retrieving the total amount of processes from a fork() call using WEXITSTATUS

Tags: c, process, fork, wexitstatus

Looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244170/display-number-of-processes-in-loop-with-fork) I do not understand Kaylum's answer. I have two questions.

1)  S/he wants to use the variable "count" to count the total number of processes spawned (that is the total number of children grandchildren etc + original process) from a fork.  I see that S/he starts off by setting count to 1 in the parent process which makes sense (to count the parent) but then S/he sets count to 1 again in the children.  Why does this make sense?  Count is already set to one and this only sets count equal to 1 again.

```
 count += WEXITSTATUS(status);
```

2) I have been investigating WEXITSTATUS and from what I can gather it returns the exit status of a process through exit.  My question is do I have to use

```
exit(0)
```

or

```
exit(1)
```

or something else for it to work.  The documentation for this is not clear.  In other words for it to work as Kaylum's

Full code segment here for convenience:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t before_pid, after_pid;
    pid_t forked_pid;
    int count;
    int i;
    int status;

    before_pid = getpid();
    count = 1; /* count self */
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        forked_pid = fork();

        if (forked_pid > 0) {
            waitpid(forked_pid, &status, 0);
            /* parent process - count child and descendents */
            count += WEXITSTATUS(status); 
    }   else {
        /* Child process - init with self count */
        count = 1;
    }
}

after_pid = getpid();
if (after_pid == before_pid) {
    printf("%d processes created\n", count);
}

return (count);
}
```

Comment: Kaylum's solution should works, but it is limited to 255 in the count : The maximum value of the exit code is 255.

Comment: Thank you.  I got it now.  I know its limited to 255 which is fine.  I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1):

> I see that S/he starts off by setting count to 1 in the parent process which makes sense (to count the parent) but then S/he sets count to 1 again in the children. Why does this make sense? Count is already set to one and this only sets count equal to 1 again.

Otherwise, each child process created in the loop could have a `count` value greater than `1`. Remember `fork()` duplicates a process from its *current* state. So for any given `fork()` in the loop, `count` isn't necessarily 1. If you print the value of `count` in the `else` part, you can easily understand this.

> I have been investigating WEXITSTATUS and from what I can gather it returns the exit status of a process through exit. My question is do I have to use exit(0) or exit(1)?

That's what `return(count)` from does. Returning from main is equivalent to calling `exit` i.e. `exit(count);`.

Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29245647/4389800) passes the count through `exit()` status. The [exit status](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) value is historically limited to an 8-bit value. So it may not work as expected for any value of `i` greater than 8 on most
platforms.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand now.  I appreciate the feedback.